# How can I gracefully handle exceptions/crashes when calling a CFFI function?

Tags: python, python-cffi

I am calling a C function from a DLL using Python's CFFI.

```
from CFFI import FFI

my_ffi = FFI()
my_dll = my_ffi.dlopen(my_dll_path)
my_ffi.cdef('int my_func();')
my_c_int = my_dll.my_func()
```

Occasionally, the C function will crash, throw an exception, or a combination of those. This has typically caused the Python script calling the C function to terminate.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
try:
    my_c_int = my_dll.my_func()
except SomeKindsOfExceptionsIncludingTheForeignFunctionCrashing:
    handle_exception()
```

Is it possible to handle exceptions raised by the foreign function as well as crashes in the foreign function? If so, how best could it be accomplished?

edit: Specifically, I would like to handle exceptions raised during the execution of code in the foreign function as well as libraries it uses. I would not like to catch and ignore hardware exceptions. A typically exception I am dealing with is caused by a socket getting unexpectedly disconnected.

I have considered calling the C function in a separate thread and monitoring that thread for a timeout. However, the C function implements part of the loss function of an optimizer, so I would like to avoid the overhead of starting a new thread each time I call the C function. Additionally, a new thread is messy and it feels like there should be an easier way to do this.

I am separately looking into ways to reduce the amount of unusual behavior coming from my DLL, though that may not come to fruition.

edit: [SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling) was suggested in the comments, however as I understand it, this would occur in the foreign function rather than on the Python side. My goal is to be able to use Python to handle such exceptions. Here is a response to a [thread](https://discuss.python.org/t/windows-fatal-exception-access-violation/19591/4) which seems to suggest that the ctypes module does not support SEH:

> If an OS exception isn’t handled at a low level by the interpreter or
> an extension module, the process crashes hard.

However, I am using the CFFI module which may have somewhat different behavior.

Comment: "the C function will throw an exception" -- this doesn't make sense: C doesn't have exceptions at all. Is this actually C++ (or something calling back into the CPython API)?

Comment: Good catch. Yes, the C function calls functions written in C++.

Comment: There isn't a good general answer -- I'd even call using a thread insufficient, since a thread still can corrupt memory shared with the parent process from a thread; one really wants an entire process boundary -- `fork()`ed off with shared file handles and other resources considered suspect if not closed in the child before it runs the suspect code -- to be safe in the general case.

Comment: It's unspecific. You must distinguish an exception defined by a programming language, and an exception defined by an OS. You mean the latter by an 'exception'. In general, you should not continue the process when an OS exception occurs, because the program state will be undefined and continuing the program may cause a damage or a security issue. If you insist, see [SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/structured-exception-handling). And if you ask on it, do a preliminary research, try to implement a prototype and ask a specific question with a [mre] and debugging details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, relent. SEH would have to be written into the foreign function, right? If there is no way to do this in Python, that's a valid answer. I updated my question to discuss the potential use of SEH.

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I don't suspect that the issues cropping up in the foreign function are particularly exotic. The typical problems I am seeing are more along the lines of a socket getting unexpectedly disconnected. I have edited my question to reduce the scope/generality.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion of using a process to isolate the code, I believe that you could also create a proper Python extension. That would require C++ skills though, not sure if that would work for you.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, I think a Python extension is potentially the direction I want to take long-term from a cleanliness and maintainability perspective. However, I think with this method, I would still have to create a new process each time I wanted to call my foreign function (now through an extension rather than through cffi). Were you thinking of another way to accomplish this that avoids starting lots of new processes?

Comment: Okay, let me clarify: If you create a proper Python wrapper, you could at least catch C++ exceptions. Those are not a sign that the program is in an irrecoverably faulty state, so they can be handled in-process. For things like segmentation faults, this isn't enough, for that you need a separate process for isolation.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for the detail. I think the answer then is that this is not possible out-of-the-box with CFFI. I'll try to go with a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indirectly use CFFI to call C++ code and catch C++ exceptions, by writing your own C wrapper around the C++ code.  To do that, you need to use CFFI in [API mode](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#api-mode-calling-the-c-standard-library) and write the wrapper in the `set_source()` part; and then you call this C wrapper using CFFI.

You can also use the CPython C API directly, but it requires the same C wrappers anyway: neither solution does anything sane about C++ exceptions, so you have to catch and convert them.